# Ubuntu 15.10 can't connect nexus 5

Tags: 15.10, usb-drive, debugging, android-studio

I have installed on my computer only Ubuntu 15.10 and I program with Android Studio, but Ubuntu can't find my Nexus 5 when I connect via USB.
I try with other smartphone (Huawei P8 Lite) and Ubuntu find the device and I debug my project on it. Why Ubuntu don't see Nexus 5?
Thanks

Comment: did you checked: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/113067/nexus-5-not-detected-in-ubuntu-14-04